# AWS CLI Windows Command to Terminate All EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need a single Windows CMD command that terminate all instances from Ohio region. I found this commands but its not working.

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances \
    --region us-east-2 \
    --instance-ids (aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]" --region us-east-2)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also where are you running this from, Windows, Linux?

Comment: i found this but it only work for linux, i need a command for windows. 
https://blog.datasyndrome.com/howto-terminate-all-ec2-instances-in-all-aws-regions-5213302ffa92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out in powershell:

```
foreach ($id in (aws ec2 describe-instances --filters --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Instance
Id]" --output text --region us-east-2)) { aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $id }
```

You can pass the `--dry-run` flag with terminate instances to confirm first if you'd like.